# How to remove these informations from the Cocos2d CCLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Every CCLayer in cocos2d have these infos (see the red rect in printscreen).

How can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in App delegate file project initilization area.

```
 [[Director sharedDirector] setDisplayStats:NO];
```

Comment: but is deprecated. I used `[[Director sharedDirector] setDisplayStats:NO];`

Comment: Yes, I forgot that sorry.